# Fluid layout Block Positioning via CSS without any height knowledge for a responsive layouted site

Tags: css, layout, fluid-layout

I planned my site on paper as a responsive layout site and try to construct very high level layout.

For the (**320 >= viewport >= 0**) part, it seems okey as intended.

however, I couldn't achieve what I want for (**480 >= viewport >= 321**)

link for what I did is: http://jsbin.com/vuliwino/2/edit

1. I don't know the heights of the DIVs, they'll be dependent
2. I know the % values of widths of DIVs. I wrote in CSS code. Width is 100% for the ones that are not written explicitly.
3. I don't want the change the order of DIVs in HTML because I've achieved (320 >= viewport) part of CSS very easily in that way. But If a solution exists which changes the order but achieves both viewport scenarios it's welcome also.

**My Requirements:**

note: numbers below are Block (abbreviated as B below) numbers. They're self-explanatory in the code.

row 1 » B1 - B4 - B5 (these will span 100%)

row 2 » B6 (span 100%)

row 3 » B3 - B7 (B3 is shorter than B7. 2 DIVS together will span 100%)

row 4 » B8 (span 100% of B7. )

row 5 » B9 (span 100% of B7.)

row 6 » B10 (span 100% of B7.)

I hope what I require has a pure CSS solution with given input.

Can you please help me?

regards

**UPDATE**

I added a mockup. I achieved scnario 1 for `/* 320 >= viewport >= 0 */`

And I want to achieve scenario 2 for `/*  480 >= viewport >= 321  */`

Block names are:

1. 1-logo
2. 2-mobile toggle menu
3. 3-primary menu
4. 4-secondary menu
5. 5-social media links
6. 6-search box
7. 7-content
8. 8-recent comments
9. 9-content from archive
10. 10-footer

[image]

(**UPDATE 2**: in the mockup image FOR SCENARIO 1, 3-4-5 means 3 at the top, 4 is below 3rd and 5 is below 4th. As I've said it's my default style and I already achieved scenario 1)

(**UPDATE 3**: the point which has been arrived with the very 1st answer to this question. I added the colorful jsbin image. 1st row is B1-B3-B4 but it should be B1-B4-B5 (refer to the mockup). Also Block 7 should be at the right of B3)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain a little better what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the height? You also keep mentioning span's, but there are no span's in your markup.

Comment: no, I don't try to compute heights, they'll be dynamic page to page. If I'd know heights, at least I could use absolute positioning. That 'd be nice & easy but heights won't be known.

Comment: It would help if you could do a mockup of what you are trying to achieve vs what you are getting.

Comment: "should be aside of each other at top level" so you want the divs to be displayed as inline? Is that it?

Comment: @AndyM hope what I added made me more clear. Sorry for my English in question. I couldn't tell verbally I think. What I got unsuccesfully is in the link I wrote in question. regards

Comment: I think I understand now. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: But I think some of your id numbers in your images don't correspond to the id's in the jsbin.

Comment: @Nikzilla I checked the id #s. If you mean logic I can't say anything but phsically, those are correct. regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/vuliwino/9/edit

Try this.

You have to use javascript to move the primary menu physically.

```
$(window).resize(resize);
resize();

function resize()
{
    console.log($(window).width());
    if($(window).width() <= 480 && $(window).width() >= 321)
    {
        $("#id3").insertAfter("#id6");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#id3").insertBefore("#id4");
    }
}
```

Use inline-blocks to make collumns.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your effort however your solution is very different from what I defined in mockup

Comment: How so? Looks exactly like your image to me.

Comment: I added the image I see from your jsbin url into my question as update3. Also wrote the differences

Comment: That is exactly what I've achieved

Comment: First row is B1-B4-B5 like you asked, B3 is to the left of B7-B10, and B6 is between B3 and B5.

Comment: Maybe the reason is my work computer browser, I don't know. I'll check from my personal computer also. According to the image you solved the case. I hope pure CSS'd be enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, because you are physically reordering the elements. You can use CSS hacks to simulate that, but JS is the most reliable way.